# Improving performance reflection - what alternatives should I consider?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection

I need to dynamically set values on a bunch or properties on an object, call it a transmission object.

There will be a fair number of these transmission objects that will be created and have its properties set in a short space of time. I want to avoid the use of reflection.

Are there alternatives? If so are there sample implementations I could look at?

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid reflection?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) to turn a `MethodInfo` into a strongly-typed delegate. This can improve performance *massively*. I have a [blog post about this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) with sample code. Note that this is only going to help if you need to set the same properties multiple times - basically it means that a lot of the type checking is done *once* when you create the delegate, rather than on every invocation.

Marc Gravell has a [HyperPropertyDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) project which achieves even better performance, but introduces an extra dependency. This project became the jumping off point for the more modern [Fast Member](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) ([github](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member)). In general you would use Fast Member over HyperProperty.

Comment: Got it thanks 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx

Comment: That's so much better then trying to make a Dynamic method

Comment: I've got some interesting examples of this in .NET 4.0 with DLR trees - hopefully for the article ;-p

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 4.0 (beta), you can do this with the updated expression trees, using `Expression.Block` and `Expression.Assign` - then compile that to a typed delegate; job done.

In .NET 2.0 and above (as Jon mentioned) HyperDescriptor is a reasonable option - it works as a custom `PropertyDescriptor` implementation, so you just do code like:

```
// store this collection for optimum performance
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(
    typeof(SomeType));
props["Name"].SetValue(obj, newName);
props["DateOfBirth"].SetValue(obj, newDoB);
```

This still has a little boxing, but that isn't actually a bottleneck.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection can be blazingly fast *if you do it right* (not as fast as static code, of course).

Finding a property-setter is slow. Invoking a delegate is fast.

You need to get and cache `Delegate` objects for each property-setter on each type of DTO. That's the slow part, but it's a one-time hit. Then you can `Invoke` each of the cached delegates for the property-setters of a given DTO type, passing in the DTO object and the new property value, but this part will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks Justice I will try your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you established with certainty that using reflection is too slow? Although reflection in .NET is *not as fast* as static code, it is still extremely fast. You should write the code in the easiest way possible - even if that uses reflection - and only come back to optimize if you notice performance problems and isolate them to your use of reflection. Most of the time, you won't have any problems. Reflection is used in all kinds of performance-sensitive code, such as ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is the fastest possible implementation. I am also looking at alternatives simply for due diligence. I do not want to be hamstrung into one technique , simply because it is the one I am familiar with, without exploring alternatives.

Comment: @Rex M I have a question in my mind. is reflection slower than member access (read/write) in dynamically typed languages like python or php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightweight code generation. Here are some articles:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/joelpob/archive/2004/04/01/105862.aspx
- [http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2005/06/lightweight_cod.html (mirror)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150914020327/http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2005/06/lightweight_cod.html)
- [Dyanamic Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: wesnerm link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Reflection got a bad rep from Java where it is (or at least used to be) very slow. This is not the case in .net so I don't understand your objection on using it. Also I agree with Rex, you can't say something has poor performance without actually measuring.

Comment: I did not say it had poor performance , I implied it ! jokes aside please see comment to rex.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "very slow". It can very easily still be a bottleneck if you use it naively... but with a bit of work (e.g. Delegate.CreateDelegate and the like) it can be made pretty nippy.