# Need a Better Way Than Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm reading a CSV file and the records are recorded as a string[]. I want to take each record and convert it into a custom object.

```
T GetMyObject<T>();
```

Currently I'm doing this through reflection which is really slow. I'm testing with a 515 Meg file with several million records. It takes under 10 seconds to parse. It takes under 20 seconds to create the custom objects using manual conversions with `Convert.ToSomeType` but around 4 minutes to do the conversion to the objects through reflection.

What is a good way to handle this automatically?

It seems a lot of time is spent in the `PropertyInfo.SetValue` method. I tried caching the properties `MethodInfo` setter and using that instead, but it was actually slower.

I have also tried converting that into a delegate like the great Jon Skeet suggested here: [Improving performance reflection , what alternatives should I consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027980/improving-performance-reflection-what-alternatives-should-i-consider), but the problem is I don't know what the property type is ahead of time. I'm able to get the delegate

```
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
foreach( var property in typeof( T ).GetProperties() )
{
    var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<,> )
    .MakeGenericType( typeof( T ), property.PropertyType ), property.GetSetMethod() );
}
```

The problem here is I can't cast the delegate into a concrete type like `Action<T, int>`, because the property type of `int` isn't known ahead of time.

Comment: Those times don't sound bad to me for a 500GB file!

Comment: Agreed, the benchmark results you stated seem reasonable.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help but 10s to parse a 500GB file is unbelievably fast.

Comment: Can you clarify how the string is converted into the custom object, and who does that conversion? That will influence your design.

Comment: @Robert Harvey 500GB in 10s is a thousand times faster than most hard drives. The fastest Itanium front side buses are around 40 GB / second, so whatever storage is being used is pretty quick. Or someone got GB and MB mixed up.

Comment: Re your comment, I added an example; at the moment it gets the mapping from the columns headers, but it could just as easily come from a `params string[]` argument.

Comment: (note it could also take a string[] for the data simply enough, rather than using `CsvReader`)

Comment: @Pete Kirkham Sorry, I typed that wrong. It's 515MB. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Re your comment; I've added a second example that uses `TypeConverter` instead of `Parse`; let me know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I'd say is write some sample code *manually* that tells you what the absolute best case you can expect is - see if your current code is worth fixing.

If you are using `PropertyInfo.SetValue` etc, then absolutely you can make it quicker, even with juts `object` - [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) might be a good start (it is *significantly* faster than raw reflection, but without making the code any more complicated).

For optimal performance, dynamic IL methods are the way to go (precompiled once); in 2.0/3.0, maybe `DynamicMethod`, but in 3.5 I'd favor `Expression` (with `Compile()`). Let me know if you want more detail?

---

Implementation using `Expression` and [`CsvReader`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), that uses the column headers to provide the mapping (it invents some data along the same lines); it uses `IEnumerable<T>` as the return type to avoid having to buffer the data (since you seem to have quite a lot of it):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
static class Program {

    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "data.csv";
        InventData(path);

        int count = 0;
        foreach (Entity obj in Read<Entity>(path))
        {
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
    static IEnumerable<T> Read<T>(string path)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        using (TextReader source = File.OpenText(path))
        using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(source,true,delimiter)) {

            string[] headers = reader.GetFieldHeaders();
            Type type = typeof(T);
            List<MemberBinding> bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CsvReader), "row");
            MethodInfo method = typeof(CsvReader).GetProperty("Item",new [] {typeof(int)}).GetGetMethod();
            Expression invariantCulture = Expression.Constant(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeof(IFormatProvider));
            for(int i = 0 ; i < headers.Length ; i++) {
                MemberInfo member = type.GetMember(headers[i]).Single();
                Type finalType;
                switch (member.MemberType)
                {
                    case MemberTypes.Field: finalType = ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType; break;
                    case MemberTypes.Property: finalType = ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType; break;
                    default: throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                Expression val = Expression.Call(
                    param, method, Expression.Constant(i, typeof(int)));
                if (finalType != typeof(string))
                {
                    val = Expression.Call(
                        finalType, "Parse", null, val, invariantCulture);
                }
                bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(member, val));
            }

            Expression body = Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(type), bindings);

            Func<CsvReader, T> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<CsvReader, T>>(body, param).Compile();
            while (reader.ReadNextRecord()) {
                yield return func(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    const char delimiter = '\t';
    static void InventData(string path)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(123456);
        using (TextWriter dest = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            dest.WriteLine("Id" + delimiter + "DateOfBirth" + delimiter + "Name");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                dest.Write(rand.Next(5000000));
                dest.Write(delimiter);
                dest.Write(new DateTime(
                    rand.Next(1960, 2010),
                    rand.Next(1, 13),
                    rand.Next(1, 28)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                dest.Write(delimiter);
                dest.Write("Fred");
                dest.WriteLine();
            }
            dest.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Second version (see comments) that uses `TypeConverter` rather than `Parse`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "data.csv";
        InventData(path);

        int count = 0;
        foreach (Entity obj in Read<Entity>(path))
        {
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
    static IEnumerable<T> Read<T>(string path)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        using (TextReader source = File.OpenText(path))
        using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(source, true, delimiter))
        {

            string[] headers = reader.GetFieldHeaders();
            Type type = typeof(T);
            List<MemberBinding> bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CsvReader), "row");
            MethodInfo method = typeof(CsvReader).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(int) }).GetGetMethod();

            var converters = new Dictionary<Type, ConstantExpression>();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                MemberInfo member = type.GetMember(headers[i]).Single();
                Type finalType;
                switch (member.MemberType)
                {
                    case MemberTypes.Field: finalType = ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType; break;
                    case MemberTypes.Property: finalType = ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType; break;
                    default: throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                Expression val = Expression.Call(
                    param, method, Expression.Constant(i, typeof(int)));
                if (finalType != typeof(string))
                {
                    ConstantExpression converter;
                    if (!converters.TryGetValue(finalType, out converter))
                    {
                        converter = Expression.Constant(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(finalType));
                        converters.Add(finalType, converter);
                    }
                    val = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(converter, "ConvertFromInvariantString", null, val),
                        finalType);
                }
                bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(member, val));
            }

            Expression body = Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(type), bindings);

            Func<CsvReader, T> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<CsvReader, T>>(body, param).Compile();
            while (reader.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                yield return func(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    const char delimiter = '\t';
    static void InventData(string path)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(123456);
        using (TextWriter dest = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            dest.WriteLine("Id" + delimiter + "DateOfBirth" + delimiter + "Name");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                dest.Write(rand.Next(5000000));
                dest.Write(delimiter);
                dest.Write(new DateTime(
                    rand.Next(1960, 2010),
                    rand.Next(1, 13),
                    rand.Next(1, 28)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                dest.Write(delimiter);
                dest.Write("Fred");
                dest.WriteLine();
            }
            dest.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do assigment in expressions.

Comment: For new objects you can (which is what we are doing here) - how do you think lambdas such as `new {Name = x.Name, Id = x.Id}` work.

Comment: I see how using DynamicMethod would work from Darin Dimitrov's link. How would you use Expression to do this? I can see creating a mapping file where you say what field is mapped to what property by doing Map( m => m.FirstName, "FirstName" ) like FluentNHibernate does. Is that what you were thinking, or something else? I'd really rather not want to create another file for this. If that's the case, using DynamicMethod would be better.

Comment: I did some sample code manually which I mentioned was under 20 seconds, so that would be my goal.

Comment: If you notice, there is lots of code there, but it only does the complex stuff *once*, compiling it into a `Func<,>` which it re-uses for the rows.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yes, I see. I like it. A lot more readable than DynamicMethod emitting too. Doing this had very fast results also. I'm actually using TypeConverter's to do the type conversion which seems to be the slow down now. I may need to re-think that portion.

Comment: I'm very familiar with TypeConverter; that would be fine if "good enough is", perhaps with HyperDescriptor (since both use boxing). But if you need the fastest possible it is better to bypass these (albeit minor) overheads, and use things like `Parse`. Or mix and match ;-p

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try and eliminate it where I can. Currently I'm just using it for everything, just to get everything working properly. Obviously, if the type is a string, then no conversion is needed, which I'm currently not even handling. I'm actually looking for TypeConverterAttribute on the properties and if one is specified, use that.

Comment: Ok. I have it implemented and it's pretty fast. I'm using parse if parse is available, otherwise grabbing the default type converter for the type, and nothing if string. The only problem I'm having now is if the type is Guid. Doing TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( property.PropertyType ) to get the converter, then getting the method by typeConverter.GetType().GetMethod( "ConvertFrom", new[] { typeof( string ) } ), then passing that into Expression.Call( Expression.New( typeConverter.GetType() ), convertFromMethod, fieldExpression ). When binding this I get the error "Argument types do not match".

Comment: In this case I would use the Guid ctor that accepts a string:  `ConstructorInfo guidCtor = typeof(Guid).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(string)});`, and use (for `Guid`) `val =  Expression.New(guidCtor, val);`

Comment: I found that no type converters work. They all have the same "Argument types do not match" issue. What is the proper way to create a type converter and call ConvertFrom on it using Expressions?

Comment: Added `TypeConverter` example (in this case *all* type-converter, but you could mix and match easily enough)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc! Is there a good place to learn Expressions? The comments on MSDN and intellisense don't really help explaining what things do. You seem to know them pretty well, which may just be from using them. :P

Comment: I've blogged about it a bit, including tricks for learning them: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/search/label/expression (read bottom up) - but apparently the MSDN documentation for 4.0 is better.

Comment: @Marc Gravell You can view my implementation here http://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `DynamicMethod` or an expression tree and build statically typed code at runtime.

This will incur a rather large setup cost, but no per-object overhead at all.
However, it's somewhat difficult to do, and will result in complicated code that is difficult to debug.