# ContructorInfo.Invoke vs delegate

Tags: .net, delegates, constructor

I've seen several questions here at SO which is about getting a delegate to create an object instead of using `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`.

Here is an example: [Using a Delegate to call a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051359/using-a-delegate-to-call-a-constructor).

I just want to know why? If it's performance-wise, why is a delegate faster?

### Update

I do understand that when creating a delegate you get rid of the validations when reusing it. That's one performance increase.

But that happens when a constructor is called through a delegate? Same thing as when doing `var a = new XXX()` or something else?

Do `ConstructorInfo.Invoke()` do the same thing as `new XXX()`? (Disregard any validation)

When using `Activator.CreateInstance()`, do it do about the same as `Constructor.Invoke()` (except any type lookup/validation).

I guess that my question boils down to: Can objects be created in different ways (like different IL instructions) or are all mention methods using the same instruction(s), but with different kinds of validations before the actual creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few reasons:

- In various places, you *have* to provide a delegate. If something requires a `Func<T>`, you can't just give it a `ConstructorInfo`.
- It's type safe - you can guarantee what type will be created (or at least a compatible type) and you know what arguments are required (if any). Calling `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`, there's plenty to go wrong at execution time every time you call it, rather than just when a delegate is created.
- It's faster, because all the validation (access, arguments) etc is performed *once* when the delegate is created, instead of every time the `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` method is called.

Comment: Are the IL about the same for a delegate as in Marcs answer as the code used by `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`? (When you take away all validations and such)

Comment: @jgauffin: Well pretty much all the code in `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` *would* be the validation. It's not clear exactly what you're asking... what sort of difference are you interested in?

Comment: So basically `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` is `validate, validate, validate, Activator.CreateInstance()`? I'm just interested in how a delegate and `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` creates the actual object. If they use the same code/IL or if there is a difference when all validation code is not counted.

Comment: @jgauffin the validation happens when playing with the `Expression`, but once compiled all that goes away. You should of course cache and re-use the delegate

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope I'm not confusing you even more :)

Comment: @jgauffin: It's still not really clear what you're looking for. The *result* is going to be a constructed object either way. Everything before that is a matter of validation before calling the constructor, basically. Each approach does validation, but at different stages - for the delegate approach, the validation is performed *once* when you build the delegate; after that it's basically like calling `new Foo()`, possibly with one level of indirection depending on how you've built the delegate.

Comment: I was looking for `after that it's basically like calling new Foo()`.