# Why are PropertyInfo SetValue and GetValue so slow?

Tags: .net, reflection, reflection.emit, propertyinfo

Why is the `PropertyInfo` methods for getting and setting a property so slow? If I build a delegate using `Reflection.Emit`, it is much faster.

Are they doing something important, so that the time they take can be justified? That is... am I missing something by using `Reflection.Emit` to build delegates instead of usign the `GetValue` and `SetValue` of the PropertyInfo (aside of development speed)?

*PS: Please, give evidence, not only guessing!*

Comment: Fyi, if you're looking for an easier way of getting a performance boost than Reflection.Emit, you could just Delegate.CreateDelegate with PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod / PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod (and cache the delegate of course).

Comment: I'd have to lock the instance of the object in the delegate. The methods `GetValue` and `SetValue` take the object instance, at the time of the call.

Comment: Delegate.CreateDelegate can create both open and closed-instance delegate objects.

Comment: It is not for easyness, I am looking for something like: "you should use `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method because of security issues." or something like that. I want to know if I am missing something.

Comment: Yeah... they say `Delegate.CreateDelegate` for `static` methods also support instance methods. Very confusing! If you didn't say I'd never know that. Thanks!

Comment: Is that really faster to (emit + create type + create delegate + call delegate) rather than (get type + get property info + get/set value)?

Comment: I only see an advantage when caching the delegate. It is faster to (get delegate from cache + call delegate) than (get property info from cache + get/set value). If results are not cached, then I guess reflection is faster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The implementation of `RuntimePropertyInfo` (which is the concrete subclass of `PropertyInfo` for runtime types) implements `GetValue` and `SetValue` by invoking the getter and setter methods via reflection (`MethodInfo.Invoke`), whereas your generated delegate probably calls the methods directly. Therefore, the question boils down to: why is `RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke` so slow when compared to a compiled invocation?

When you decompile (or look at the reference sources for) `RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke`, you can see that this is probably because `Invoke` carries out a lot of tasks:

- it performs consistency checks (do the number and types of parameters passed match the signature? does the instance passed match the declaring type? was an instance passed although the method is static?),
- it performs visibility and (if visibility checks are circumvented) security checks,
- it unwraps the parameters array, treating ref parameters in a special way so that they can be written back to later,
- it unboxes parameters if necessary,
- it needs to find the method pointer based on the runtime type handle and method handle associated with the RuntimeMethodHandle and then invoke the method,
- it boxes the return value if necessary, and
- it boxes and puts into the parameter array any ref/out parameters.

The runtime will perform similar consistency, security, and visibility checks when it compiles your delegate into executable native code. It also emits code for boxing/unboxing, etc. However, it only needs to do these things once, and can then guarantee that the code is safe to execute. This makes the actual method call a very cheap operation (load the parameters and jump to the method address).

In contrast, every call to `RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke` (and thus to `GetValue`/`SetValue`) needs to repeat all the work, since the context - parameters, instance, and usage of the return type - is not known. And this is probably why it is so slow.

About what you might be missing: if you emit your own property invocation delegates, you of course need to deal with boxing/unboxing, ref/out parameters, etc. yourself.

Answer (score 18):

There is no need to use Emit. It is far more easy to use Expression.
You can speed up the access as described in 
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669142/2534462). 
The helper class creates a "method pointer" (Action/Func) to the getter or setter. If you reuse the Action/Func you will be able to perform as fast as a normal setter.

```
   // creating setter (once)
   var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(field);
   var setter = FastInvoke.BuildUntypedSetter<T>(propertyInfo));

   // usage somehow later in a loop of data
   foreach(var myobject in MySource)
   {
     setter(myobject, myValue)
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027980/improving-performance-reflection-what-alternatives-should-i-consider

Comment: @Fried Your link is broken whereas sky-devs link works. I guess thats his point.

Comment: I put the article on SO => see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660097/is-it-possible-to-speed-this-method-up/17669142#17669142

Comment: Does not work if the property is private set or init

Comment: @jjxtra Private properties seems to work with correct binding flags. If not, cann you give an example?: var propertyInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty("PrivateName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var propertyGetter = FastInvoke.BuildUntypedGetter<Person>(propertyInfo!);