# Access VB property based on name as string - Fastest Option

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reflection, system.reflection

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web app in VB and I am required to output a set of data to a table format, and to allow the user to configure the order and presence of columns from an available set. The data set is stored as a list of the object type representing the row model.

Currently, I implement this using [CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.90).aspx). Iterating over an ordered list of property names and outputting the value from the instance of the row model. However, based on testing this seems to be a major bottleneck in the process.

I've seen a recommendation to store delegates to get the property, against the string representation of the property's name. So, I can presumably do something like this:

```
Public Delegate Function GetColumn(ByRef RowObj As RowModel) As String

Dim GetPropOne As GetColumn = Function(ByRef RowObj As RowModel) RowObj.Prop1.ToString()

Dim accessors As New Hashtable()

accessors.Add("Prop1", GetPropOne)
```

Then, loop through and do something like this:

```
Dim acc As GetColumn = accessors(ColumnName)

Dim val As String = acc.Invoke(currentRow)
```

It looks faster, but it also looks like more maintenance. If this is indeed faster, is there a way I can dynamically build something like this? I'm thinking:

```
Public Delegate Function GetObjectProperty(Instance As Object) As Object

For Each prop In GetType(RowModel).GetProperties()
    Dim acc As GetObjectProperty = AddressOf prop.GetValue
    columns.Add(prop.Name, acc)
Next

Dim getColVal As GetObjectProperty = columns(ColumnName)

Dim val As String = getColVal.Invoke(currentRow).ToString()
```

Open to suggestions for different approaches.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah, I think it will work, but I'm unclear on whether there is a performance benefit vs calling CallByName.

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing to turn a SOAP response into a Data Table

```
Public Function ObjectToDataSource(objName) As DataSet
    Dim CollName = ""
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    For Each m As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objName.GetType().GetProperties()
        If m.CanRead Then
            If InStr(m.PropertyType.ToString, "[]") <> 0 Then
                CollName = m.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Dim CollObj
    CollObj = CallByName(objName, CollName, CallType.Get)
    If CollObj.length = 0 Then
        Call EndTask("No Supply Chains to display", "Royal Mail failed to return Supply Chain information for these credentials", 3)
    Else
        Dim dt_NewTable As New DataTable(CollName)
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_NewTable)
        Dim ColumnCount = 0
        For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In CollObj(0).GetType().GetProperties()
            If p.CanRead Then
                If p.Name <> "ExtensionData" Then
                    dt_NewTable.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType)
                    ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Dim rowcount = CollObj.Length - 1
        For r = 0 To rowcount
            Dim rowdata(ColumnCount - 1) As Object
            For c = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
                rowdata(c) = CallByName(CollObj(r), dt_NewTable.Columns.Item(c).ToString, CallType.Get)
            Next
            dt_NewTable.Rows.Add(rowdata)
            rowdata = Nothing
        Next
    End If
    Return ds
End Function
```

This is specific to my needs in terms of getting CollName and not requiring ExtensionData

Answer (score 0):

If `ColumnName` is the same name as one of the `RowModel`'s properties I don't see why you need the long workaround with delegates...

An [**extension method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) which gets only the property you want right now is both faster and consumes less memory.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetProperty(ByVal Instance As Object, ByVal PropertyName As String, Optional ByVal Arguments As Object() = Nothing) As Object
        Return Instance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(Instance, Arguments)
    End Function
End Module
```

**Example usage:**

```
currentRow.GetProperty("Prop1")
'or:
currentRow.GetProperty(ColumnName)
```

Comment: Are you sure `CallByName` is the bottleneck? Because compared to Reflection they both seem to be able to get properties almost equally fast (usually takes less than a millisecond to do so).

Comment: I assumed CallByName and the System.Reflection methods worked the same under the hood, hence why I was thinking about setting up the hashtable of delegate functions to access the properties. My concern is that this creates a maintenance burden when updating the row model. If I can build that set of functions dynamically then that would be better. I guess my concern is where the performance impact from reflection is coming from. Is it when I iterate the properties collection, or is it when I call the GetValue method, or both? I haven't actually tested any of the methods I propose above, yet.

Comment: @ScottOliver : If you use your last code example then the `HashSet` or `Dictionary` will be creating the overhead. This is because your last code block is just a more redundant way of doing what I do above.

Comment: @ScottOliver : I beleive that Reflection will always have a certain overhead (still only about 1 ms per call, though) because there's a lot of calls and evaluations that it has to do. **Therefore** the fastest way of doing this is what you do in your first code block, because it doesn't utilize reflection. So by gaining performance you lose "dynamicness".

Comment: OK, so, looking back at the more verbose but presumably faster method: Is it possible to build something like that dynamically without incurring performance cost due to reflection? EDIT: Hadn't seen the latest comment. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottOliver : Check the answer in the following question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027980/improving-performance-reflection-what-alternatives-should-i-consider

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.