# Class to return different types - best option?

Tags: c#, class

I need a class that can work with string properties to store data on a structured (class) list but at the same type to have a way to return an index that acts as the order I need to set up my data.

the class can be something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int int1 = 0;
    public int int2 = 0;
    public int int3 = 0;
    public int int4 = 0;

    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public string string3 { get; set; }
    public string string4 { get; set; }
}
```

then I can use my class to store the data in the class structured format:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Mylocation\MyTextFileToRead.txt";    //tab delimeted file
Encoding fileEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
List<MyClass> myDataList = new List<MyClass>();
List<string> simpleData = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, fileEncoding).ToList();
MyClass index = new MyClass();

foreach (var line in simpleData)
{
    var lineSplit = line.Split('\t');
    MyClass myClassElement = new MyClass
    {
        string1 = lineSplit[index.int1],
        string2 = lineSplit[index.int2],
        string3 = lineSplit[index.int3],
        string4 = lineSplit[index.int4],
    };
    myDataList.Add(myClassElement);

}
```

I use the index to map each property from the text file and then to store each filed values in the corresponding string property.

I do not wish to use object types and have the properties to return a string value and cast it as (int) for the index. I was advised not to use objects as much as possible.
The use of Const fields did not work for the index unless I use the type name of the class (instead an instance of the class), but I don't know if it helps or if this is a better programming option.

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this, but would be very welcome with relevant feedback.

Comment: For me this feels wrong, your class is not related to your file so why would you store the order, i do not see how this is relevant. From your example, you only need the order when reading the file.

Comment: the text file has properties which I know the order, the index is who I know which field needs to go to after the split. the order is key.

Comment: You did not get good advice, always avoid stringly typing. That you have to change the class declaration when the file structure changes is normal and expected.  You have make changes anyway when you use stringly typing, they will be harder to get correct.

Comment: Still does not make sense. If you text file knows the order, your class does not need to know it. Simply push right data to properties of class, maybe you can show your file data?

Comment: for each string -> prop1 + '\t' + prop2+ '\t' + prop3+ '\t' + prop4 but how do i set the order for the split?

Answer (score 2):

To return two diffrent types from one function you can use the way that was [introduce in C# 7.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

It works like this:

```
public (int, string) MyFunc()
{
    //do something
    return (VarThatInt, VarThatString);
}

//and in main class u call it like this:

(varInt, varString) = MyFunc();
```

Comment: I'm limited to c#4

Comment: You didnt mentioned that, so could u call your downbote back?

Comment: The OP cannot downvote as you're required to have 125 reputation to do so. I don't know who did, but your answer definitely **does not** deserve a downvote. -- By the way, what you're suggesting is called a _Tuple_. :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent: I'm new at this, sorry. What do you mean with "Tuple"?

Comment: @ptuga : It's what michasaucer suggested in his/her answer. A Tuple is simply speaking a set of elements that are in a certain order. `(int, string)` is a tuple containing an `int` and a `string`.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: Is it possible if you could have a look at my comments bellow where I asked about looping through a class with "myClassElement.PROP = lineSplit[index]; where index loops from zero to n and 'PROP' loops from property 1 to property n. That would be my ideal solution. Is there such a thing?"?

Comment: @michasaucer: what means "call your downbote back"? using C#4 how can we use these so called "Tuple" in my class? How can I define these pair properties? Can you give me an example based on `MyClass` type?

Answer (score 1):

using KeyValuePair to store one property and index, use list  of  KeyValuePair to store one line , and use dic  Dictionary to store file .

```
      List<int> orderIndexList = new List<int> { 2, 1, 4, 0 };
        Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> data = new Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>();

        int lineNumber = 0;
        foreach (var line in simpleData)
        {
            var lineSplit = line.Split('\t');
            List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> listLine = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
            orderIndexList.ForEach(index => listLine.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(index, lineSplit[index])));
            data.Add(++lineNumber, listLine);
        }
        return data;
```

Comment: I definitely would like to use a class.

Answer (score 0):

Return a class that has the two desired outputs. You can even return a third variable to tell the receiving code, which output to use.

```
public myClass{   
  String TextValue;
  int NumberValue;
  bool IsReturnString; 
}
```

You would return an object of `myClass`.

Comment: the inf field can perfectly be a read-only but the string needs to store data to be able to use the structure to store data and to give it to the list. My class can be whatever is the best solution. I just need to know if what I presented is suitable and if there is a better option.

Comment: using an index in the foreach loop after the split `                index = 0;
                var lineSplit = line.Split('\t');
                MyClass myClassElement = new MyClass
                {
                    string1 = lineSplit[index],
                    string2 = lineSplit[++index],
                    string3 = lineSplit[++index],
                    string4 = lineSplit[++index],
                    // ...
                    // string... = lineSplit[++index], if more properties exist
                };` seems logic?

Comment: It works because the rule is first property gets index 0 and last property gets index n. But if I have many properties, is this possible using a loop to set each property? As far as I know Reflection can give you the name but not the property itself which is what I need. Something like `myClassElement.PROP = lineSplit[index];` where index loops from zero to n and 'PROP' loops from property 1 to property n. That would be my ideal solution. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @ptuga : Reflection does not only give you the name, it gives you a representation of the whole property which you can use to dynamically manipulate objects with. You use [`Type.GetProperty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty) to get this representation/template and then [`SetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_SetValue_System_Object_System_Object_) to change it, specifying _which instance_ of your class that you want to modify.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: You are right. I've used `PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();` and `property.SetValue(myClassElement, lineSplit[index])` in a foreach loop to navigate trough each property and to set the value (based on the index). On a class with many properties it takes ~5 times more that the traditional way `(myClassElement.property = value)` but on a smaller class it's much faster. Any reason why I shouldn't do it like this?

Comment: I mean, any reason why I shouldn't use Reflection (apart of possibly being slower in some cases)?

Comment: @ptuga : Apart from the possibility that there might be a better solution, I don't know of any reason why you shouldn't use reflection, no. For the record, there are ways to make reflection faster in some cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028058

Comment: @Visual Vincent: This is the point where I really struggle. Is there a basic simple example that I can use to extrapolate to my class? What are we delegating? The `typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()`? A bit more guidance would take me further.

Comment: @ptuga : The setter of the property, i.e. [`PropertyInfo.SetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2). But if you're only setting each property once it won't make a difference. Though like the answer(s) suggest, there are alternatives to reflection that you can try.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: For 'alternatives to reflection' I'll need to get much better and know much more than what I know at the moment. At this level I can work with simpler examples. Thanks a lot for the support.